# Not able to run the PySpark code locally after

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I am not able to run the PySpark code which is imported from the data bricks after completing all required configuration setup for spark even though I am getting errors as shown below. Please help me with a solution.

code:

```
# Databricks notebook source
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

# COMMAND ----------

conf = SparkConf().setAppName('Read File')

# COMMAND ----------

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf=conf)

# COMMAND ----------

text = sc.textFile('sample.txt')

# COMMAND ----------

print(text.collect())

# COMMAND ----------

sc.stop()
# COMMAND ----------
```

Error:

```
C:\Users\Abhishikth\Desktop>spark-submit 'fsc2.py'
21/10/18 08:03:34 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to get main class in JAR with error 'File file:/C:/Users/Abhishikth/Desktop/'fsc2.py' does not exist'.  Please specify one with --class.
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.error(SparkSubmit.scala:968)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:486)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:894)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1039)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1048)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Comment: Can you run `spark-submit fsc2.py` without the quotes?

Comment: @RobertKossendey I tried but this error I got as a result: C:\Users\Abhishikth\Desktop>spark-submit fsc2.py
21/10/18 09:22:36 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
python: can't open file 'C:\Users\Abhishikth\Desktop\fsc2.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

Comment: Where does your file sit then? It seems that you don't have the file on your Desktop

Comment: @RobertKossendey I changed the location of the source file and data text file  to one where both are the same folder and  run the spark code without quotes because if I use the quotes result is the same as the above comment and then-current result as shown below :   

21/10/18 09:41:37 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
21/10/18 09:41:38 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 3.1.2

Comment: You need to run spark-submit in the same directory that your files are in

Comment: @RobertKossendey Both files are in the same directory even though the result is the same as above